# Dense cluster layout

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to create a dense cluster like this without having to move the HTML source manually:

[image: Dense cluster layout]

Here's an example using flexbox without the source ordered for it to be dense:

```css
ul {
  max-width: 20ch;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  outline: 2px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 1px;
  padding: 0.15em 0.3em;
  margin: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Short</li>
  <li>Bit longer</li>
  <li>Much longer one</li>
  <li>Bit shorter</li>
  <li>Massive Long Super Scrumptious</li>
  <li>Smol</li>
  <li>Somewhat long</li>
</ul>
```

Now I know that with grid you can have `grid-auto-flow: row dense` but I don't know how to have the items intrinsically sized rather than prescribed by the grid - I don't think it's even possible:

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  width: fit-content;
  outline: 2px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 1px;
  padding: 0.15em 0.3em;
  margin: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Short</li>
  <li>Bit longer</li>
  <li>Much longer one</li>
  <li>Bit shorter</li>
  <li>Massive Long Super Scrumptious</li>
  <li>Smol</li>
  <li>Somewhat long</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You cannot do this with CSS alone

Answer (score -1):

Try using following properties on your grid items:

```
 <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="box1">Short</div>
      <div class="box2">Bit longer</div>
      <div class="box3">Much longer one</div>
      <div class="box4">Bit shorter</div>
      <div class="box5">Massive Long Super Scrumptious</div>
      <div class="box6">Smol</div>
      <div class="box7">Somewhat long</div>
    </div >

    .wrapper {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
      grid-auto-rows: 100px;
    }
    
    .box1 {
      grid-column-start: 1;
      grid-column-end: 1;
      grid-row-start: 1;
      grid-row-end: 1;
    }
    
    .box2 {
      grid-column-start: 2;
      grid-column-end:3;
      grid-row-start: 1;
      grid-row-end: 1;
    }
.box3 {
      grid-column-start: 1;
      grid-column-end:3;
      grid-row-start: 2;
      grid-row-end: 2;
    }
.box4 {
      grid-column-start: 1;
      grid-column-end:2;
      grid-row-start: 3;
      grid-row-end: 3;
    }
.box5 {
      grid-column-start: 3;
      grid-column-end: 3;
      grid-row-start: 3;
      grid-row-end: 3;
    }
.box6 {
      grid-column-start: 1;
      grid-column-end: 3;
      grid-row-start: 3;
      grid-row-end: 4;
    }
.box7 {
      grid-column-start: 1;
      grid-column-end:2;
      grid-row-start: 4;
      grid-row-end: 4;
    }
```

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row-start)

Comment: How would this create the desired layout in the picture I provided

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve intricate CSS that requires changing when you add more HTML elements etc. This also looks like I'll only get two columns rather than the flexible layout I showed in the question

Comment: Check updated answer if you can change class names in HTML grid system allows you to create such flexible layouts.

Comment: This is not a flexible layout, it's a hardcoded layout. I appreciate your trying to help but this is wasting both our time